# Проблема с установкой CPR c++

Tags: cmake, clion, lib, vcpkg

Я устанавливаю библиотеку cpr на clion, использую cmake. Сама библиотека была установлена через vcpkg.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(project main.cpp)

include_directories(C:/vcpkg/packages/cpr_x64-windows/include)

link_directories(C:/vcpkg/packages/cpr_x64-windows/lib)

include_directories(C:/vcpkg/packages/curl_x64-windows/include)

link_directories(C:/vcpkg/packages/curl_x64-windows/lib)

target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE cpr)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cpr/cpr.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cpr::Response r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{"https://google.com/"});
    r.status_code;                  // 200
    r.header["content-type"];       // application/json; charset=utf-8
    r.text;                         // JSON text string
    return 0;
}
```

При попытке запуска ошибка:

```
FAILED: project.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.obj -o project.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libproject.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lcpr  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcpr: No such file or directory
```

Почему это происходит и как это исправить?